# FastAPI swaggerUI shows nested routes twice

Tags: python, swagger-ui, openapi, fastapi

I have a configuration like this in the `routes/__init__.py`

```
## api/routes/__init__.py
router = APIRouter()
router.include_router(models_router, prefix="/models", tags=["models"])
...
```

And here is the `main.py` that includes them.

```
## main.py
from api.routes import router as api_router
def get_app():
    app = FastAPI()
    app.include_router(api_router, prefix = "/api")
    ...

app = get_app()
```

Now inside the models router I have two more nested routes like this:

```
## api/routes/models.py
router.include_router(
    fields_router, 
    prefix="/{model_id}/fields", 
    tags=["fields"],
    dependencies=[Depends(pre_model_validation)]
)
router.include_router(
    model_data_router, 
    prefix="/{model_id}/data", 
    tags=["model_data"],
    dependencies=[Depends(pre_model_validation)]
)
```

While this works, when I open the localhost and use the generated SwaggerUI docs, it shows something like this

[image: swagger ui docs]:

The nested endpoints are also appearing from inside the `/models` API as well as from their separate `/fields` and `/model_data` APIs. How do I isolate the nested routes in a way that they appear as separate API in swagger docs but stay defined inside the `/models` API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want all endpoints to be under the root path `/api/models/` but want the Swagger docs to just show them only once, under the respective 'fields' or 'model_data' tags, while keeping the following under the 'models' tag:

- Get Models For Site
- Create Models
- Update Content Type

If the above is correct, instead of nesting the imports, you might want to split them using the same root path as needed, as follows:

```py
# api/routes/__init__.py
router = APIRouter()

router.include_router(
    models_router, 
    prefix="/models", 
    tags=["models"]
)

router.include_router(
    fields_router, 
    prefix="/models/{model_id}/fields", 
    tags=["fields"]
)

router.include_router(
    models_router, 
    prefix="/models/{model_id}/data", 
    tags=["model_data"]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Some workaround can be implemented having the following structure. For demonstration purposes everything is put together:

```
fields_router = APIRouter()
...

model_data_router = APIRouter()
...

models_router = APIRouter()
...


aggregated_models_router = APIRouter()
aggregated_models_router.include_router(
    fields_router, 
    prefix="/{model_id}/fields", 
    tags=["fields"],
    dependencies=[Depends(pre_model_validation)]
)
aggregated_models_router.include_router(
    model_data_router, 
    prefix="/{model_id}/data", 
    tags=["model_data"],
    dependencies=[Depends(pre_model_validation)]
)
aggregated_models_router.include_router(
    models_router, 
    prefix="", 
    tags=["models"]
)
...

router = APIRouter()
router.include_router(aggregated_models_router, prefix="/models")
...
```

Without the `tags` argument in the main router you'll get only `fields`, `model_data` and `models` sections without any duplicates

Comment: This one helped me. Setting the tags only for the endpoints you want to see in the docs seems to be helping. All it takes is to remove the tags from other routers.

Comment: yup the last statement here is the key for me!